# Opening the iOS8 share menu without a share button

Tags: twitter, unity-game-engine, ios8

I want to show a share button in my unity iOS game, and when the user taps it open the sharing menu that you get from the standard cocoatouch share button. The only reference I've found so far says that to open the share menu you add a standard share button. Obviously I don't have that option.

I'm hoping there's some simple ObjC call where I can pass it an image and have it open the sharing menu on top of my unity game.

That might not be even possible, given the nature of opengl surfaces and cocoatouch. If that's the case, I'd like to know if there's any simple way to share directly to twitter, and where the documentation is for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like UIActivityViewController is the class you want, however I'm not familiar enough with how you'd wire this into Unity to give a complete answer.

You'll need to present the activity view controller from another view controller. I'm not sure how Unity wraps this stuff up, but there's a chance there's one attached to the main UIWindow (UIWindow has a rootViewController property). If you can get at those things somehow, you could probably present it from there.

For example it would probably involve something like this:

```
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[@"Perhaps a high score/brag string here?"];

UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

UIActivityViewController *share = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

// warning: these two lines would require iOS 8, but they only govern where the popup points
share.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(window.bounds)-1, CGRectGetMidY(window.bounds)-1, 2, 2);
share.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = window;

[window.rootViewController presentViewController:share animated:YES completion:nil];
```